# Efficiently calculating the inverse of a matrix $A+D$, where $A^{-1}$ is known and D is diagonal with few non-zero points

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, computational-complexity

Lets say I have a $(N,N)$ matrix $A$  and want to quickly calculate the inverse of an updated matrix $A' = A+D$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with only a few non-zero entries with positions $M = \{m_i\}$

i.e

$$
D_{i,j} = \begin{cases}
    d_n,& \text{if } i=j \text{ and } i,j\in M  \\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

What I would like to do: quickly compute $A'^{-1}$ using $A^{-1}$ (already known) using the woodbury formula (although I am open to other solutions)

This requires a good factorisation of $D$ - my original choice was

$D = \sqrt{V}\cdot I_N \cdot V$, with $V = \sqrt{D}$

In the woodbury formula, we have

$$ 
(A+D)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1} V ( I_N +VA^{-1}V)^{-1}VA^{-1}
$$

This is not particularly useful, as the center term $ (I_N + VA^{-1}V)$ is a $(N,N)$ matrix & so is as costly to compute as the original inverse.

It seems to me that this should be fairly straightforward to do with a better choice of factorisation for the update (or maybe via a different route), but I'm not sure what to pick for the substitute.

---

A better solution:

If we set e.g $M=(0,3,5)$ - that is, the nonzero diagonal entries of D, then we can do this via setting $U=V^T$, and

$$
V = \begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 0&0&0&0&0\\
    0       & 0&0&1&0&0\\
    0       & 0&0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Then $UV^T = \text{diag}(1,0,0,1,0,1)$

This is good - we are now able to compute the $ (I_N + VA^{-1}V)$ much more efficiently, as this is a 3x3 table instead of a 6x6.

For a 1000x1000 matrix with 25 diagonal updates, I see approximately a 30x speedup with this method v.s vanilla via eigen.
Any ideas for further improvements?

Comment: What is $U$ in the Woodbury formula above? My take is that you need to exploit the sparsity of $D$ in the calculation. For example, use a permutation matrix to place all non-zero elements of $D$ in one diagonal submatrix, and then use a block-matrix formulation (where 3 our of 4 submatrices of $D$ are zero, potentially reducing quite a bit of computations).

Comment: @cjferes sorry, copied the formula over too quickly - in the above U=V

i updated the post with some further ideas I have - made some progress